# How to redirect to a different url inside the vue-router beforeRouteEnter hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am building an admin page with Vue.js 2 and I want to prevent unauthenticated users from accessing the `/admin` route and redirect them to `/login`. For that I have used the In-Component Guard `beforeRouteEnter` in the Admin component like follows

```
...
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  if(userNotLogedIn) {
    this.$router.push('/login');
  }
}
```

The problem here is that `this` is not defined in `beforeRouteEnter` hook. So what's the proper way to access `$router` and redirect to a different url in this case ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) states that:

> The `beforeRouteEnter` guard does NOT have access to `this`, because the
>   guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new
>   entering component has not even been created yet.

You can redirect to another page by calling `next` like this:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  if(userNotLogedIn) {
    next('/login');
  }
}
```

Here is another way to accomplish the same result: So instead of using `beforeRouteEnter` on each protected route, you could define protected routes in your router configuration using a `meta` property, then use `beforeEach` hook on all the routes and check for protected routes and redirect to login page when needed:

```
let router = new Router({    
  mode: 'history',    
  routes: [    
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        auth: true // A protected route
      },
    },    
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login, // Unprotected route
    },
  ]
})

/* Use this hook on all the routes that need to be protected 
instead of beforeRouteEnter on each one explicitly */

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {    
  if (to.meta.auth && userNotLoggedIn) {
    next('/login')
  }    
  else {
    next()
  }    
})

// Your Vue instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  // ...
})
```

Comment: With this solution, u can navigate with browser arrows and see protected route component information after user logout :/

Comment: @nrkz once logged in and when you want to forward the user, you should replace the login route in the history instead of pushing a new route.