# vue.js - Redirect depending on a value set on the Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to redirect a user depending on whether a value is set on the Vue instance. Currently, I am using a [Global Route Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) like this.

This is not a working example

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  next(vm => {
    if (!vm.value) {
      vm.value = 123
      return {path: '/url'}
    }
  })
})
```

Do I need to call `next('/url')` in the if statement perhaps? Or is there a better way to redirect conditionally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701595/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-url-inside-the-vue-router-beforerouteenter-hook?rq=1) however they are not using the instance. Not sure how they are getting `userNotLoggedIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the root Vue instance by using `router.app` as explained [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html)

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(!router.app.value){
        router.app.value = 123
        next('/url')
        return
    }

    next()
})
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go. I spotted that but 
"The root Vue instance the router was injected into."
made me think it was only the initial `Vue()` rather than each instance.

Comment: If you have multiple Vue instance the route state will be shared.